# explanation for real-time behavior

Tags: java

one of the BUZZWORD of java is "multithreaded" which "The benefits of multithreading are better interactive responsiveness and real-time behavior." but I don't understand what real-time behavior means which is improved in multithreading in java, whould you please explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers can't do anything simultaneously. So if you watch a movie, sound and video do not come at the same time. In reality, your CPU does it in short sequences, like show a movie-frame, play a few notes of music, show another frame etc. If you have n cores (or n processors), you computer can do at most n things at the same time. Now multithreading (running a few threads at the same time) allows for better real-time feeling for the end user, as more things happen at the same time.